# create a list in javascript from AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

hi i have a function that get information from xml data and print markers on  google map 
my problem is that i want to create a path between one point to the other point 
this is the code that retrive the data 
 `

```
  $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"PipeServlet?op=1",
                dataType:"xml",
                success: function(xml){
                    // Parses the data from xml
                    var newLat, newLon, newDesc,newName;
                    $(xml).find("deal").each(function(){
                        newName = $(this).find("name").text();
                        newLat = $(this).find("lat").text();
                        newLon = $(this).find("lon").text();
                        newDesc = $(this).find("desc").text();
                        // Displaying the Coupons on the map
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLon),
                            map: map,
                            title: newName,
                            html: newDesc,
                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                        });`
```

So i want to add the date i retrive to a list and draw a lines like in this code  :

```
mapLine = new google.maps.Polyline({map : map,
                                        strokeColor   : '#ff0000',
                                        strokeOpacity : 0.6,
                                        strokeWeight  : 4,
                                        path:[new google.maps.LatLng(33.240547551860935,35.6153623373566),new google.maps.LatLng(33.240009149357576,35.61381738496402)]
                                       });`
```

I want the line        `path:[new google.maps.LatLng(33.240547551860935,35.6153623373566),new google.maps.LatLng(33.240009149357576,35.61381738496402)]` will be create in dynamic way
  thanks for yours help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build an array: `var path = new Array();`

and add your object at the end of it: `path.push(position);`

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"PipeServlet?op=1",
            dataType:"xml",
            success: function(xml){
                // Parses the data from xml
                var newLat, newLon, newDesc,newName;
                var path = new Array();
                $(xml).find("deal").each(function(){
                    newName = $(this).find("name").text();
                    newLat = $(this).find("lat").text();
                    newLon = $(this).find("lon").text();
                    newDesc = $(this).find("desc").text();
                    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(newLat,newLon);
                    path.push(position);
                    // Displaying the Coupons on the map
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: position,
                        map: map,
                        title: newName,
                        html: newDesc,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                    });
                ...
                });
                mapLine = new google.maps.Polyline({map : map,
                                strokeColor   : '#ff0000',
                                strokeOpacity : 0.6,
                                strokeWeight  : 4,
                                path:path
                });
                ...
```